# How to add two id together

Tags: javascript, jquery, contact-form-7

I am working on a site which opens a href link on a site when the form is submitted on contact form-7. I have a question: It is opening one link. But I want to open two links simultaneously when the form is sent. I dont know how to achieve this.

Please help

```js
document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
  location = document.getElementById("link").getAttribute("href");
}, false);

document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
  location = document.getElementById("link2").getAttribute("href");
}, false);
```

```html
<a href="http://www.annualpm.com/wp-content/uploads/Fabius-GS-User-Manual.pdf" target="_blank" id="link">
  <p><img style="height:40px;" src="http://www.annualpm.com/wp-content/uploads/Hopstarter-Software-Adobe-Acrobat-Standard.ico">Fabius GS User Manual</p>
</a>
<a href="http://www.annualpm.com/wp-content/uploads/FabiusGSSpecSheet.pdf" target="_blank" id="link2">
  <p><img style="height:40px;" src="http://www.annualpm.com/wp-content/uploads/Hopstarter-Software-Adobe-Acrobat-Standard.ico">Fabius GS SpecSheet</p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 'location' redirects the current window, you can only do this once. Try using 'open' instead. Note: this will open the link in a new tab.

See: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {

 window.open(document.getElementById("link").getAttribute("href"));
setTimeout(function(){
 window.open(document.getElementById("link2").getAttribute("href"));
},500);

}, false );
</script>
```

the `setTimeout` function prevents the browser to flag the second link as a popup (in that case the second window will be blocked) :)

Comment: Most browsers will only allow one open() per event and it needs to be synchronous